# Code not getting called on User Layer

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am trying to write some code on `validateField` table method of `RetailInventItemLabel` Table, but it seems that it does not call, when I delete user layer, my breakpoint hit and default code seems calling.

This is AX 2012 CU 7

Any ideas  ?

Comment: What layer did you code on? - You are saying "delete the user layer"...?

Comment: in wrote code in user layer, but its not getting called, but when i delete user layer, default code(sys layer) is executing properly.

Comment: Can you post all the code involved - complete method? Also make sure that if you do changes that you do "build incremental cil", then log off and back on again.

Comment: Last time when this problem occurred I moved my code to form level, but now code is working on table method, may be i was missing log off\ log on part.

Answer (score 1):

I checked back after a couple of months, code is calling fine, as @private said I may be missing restart of AX client after I build incremental CIL.